# Running spring mvc + spring boot gradle java 9 project with end's up with java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/sql/SQLException

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle

I've got a really simple application that perfectly works with Java 1.8, it contains a Main class like

```
package com.company.getworks.start;


import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan()
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class ApplicationMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ApplicationMain.class, args);
    }

}
```

and a class with `@RestContoller` which contains only one method with `@RequestMapping("/hello")`

I've added module-info.java that looks like

```
module com.company.getworks.start {
    requires spring.boot;
    requires spring.webmvc;
}
```

And my build.gradle is

```
group 'com.company'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = 1.9

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    final def springVersion='4.3.10.RELEASE'
    final def springBootVersion='1.5.6.RELEASE'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    compile (group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-webmvc', version: springVersion) {
        exclude group: 'commons-logging', module: 'commons-logging'
    }
    compile(group: "org.springframework.boot", name: "spring-boot-starter-web", version: springBootVersion) {
        exclude group: 'commons-logging', module: 'commons-logging'
    }
}

ext.moduleName = 'com.company.getworks.start'

compileJava {
    inputs.property("moduleName", moduleName)
    doFirst {
        options.compilerArgs = [
            '--module-path', classpath.asPath,
            '--add-modules', 'spring.boot',
            '--add-modules', 'spring.webmvc',
    ]
    classpath = files()
    }
}
```

Running `clean compileJava` ends with Build successful, but when I am trying to run my ApplicationMain.java it ends with `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot instantiate interface org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextInitializer : org.springframework.boot.context.ConfigurationWarningsApplicationContextInitializer 
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/sql/SQLException`
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think you should add `--add-modules java.sql` to your `java` command where you start your application

Comment: Spring Boot 1.5 doesn’t support Java 9

Comment: The NoClassDefFoundError suggests there may be a custom class loader in the picture that delegates to the boot loader instead of the platform class loader.  There is no guarantee that all java.* classes are visible via the boot loader. Maybe this is something that is fixed in a newer version of Spring Boot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to

1) upgrade to spring boot 2

2) change my dependencies list to

```
dependencies {
    final def springVersion='4.3.10.RELEASE'
    final def springBootVersion='2.0.0.RELEASE'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    compile (group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-webmvc', version: springVersion) {
        exclude group: 'commons-logging', module: 'commons-logging'
    }
    compile(group: "org.springframework.boot", name: "spring-boot-starter-web", version: springBootVersion) {
        exclude group: 'commons-logging', module: 'commons-logging'
        exclude group: 'javax.annotation', module: 'javax.annotation-api'
    }
}
```

3) Update module-info.java

```
module com.company.getworks.start {
    requires spring.boot;
    requires spring.webmvc;
    requires spring.context;
    requires spring.boot.autoconfigure;
    requires spring.web;
    opens com.company.getworks.start;
    exports com.company.getworks.web;
}
```

where `com.company.getworks.web` is package that contains my @RestController class

4) As correctly mentioned @miroh add --add-modules java.sql to my java command